# Relationship for cosine of angle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

If $x$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$, $y$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $a$ and $p$, and $z$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $b$ and $p$, can we write $z$ in terms of $x$, $y$ and the magnitudes of $a$, $b$, and $p$?

That is, no dot products should appear in the relation.

All vectors are in $4$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not even in three dimensions.  Envision a physical model: three rods, called $a$, $b$, $p$, extending out from a point, but connected to it by flexible joints.  A triangular metal plate joins rods $a$ and $b$, so the angle between rods $a$ and $b$ is fixed.  Another plate joints rods $a$ and $p$, so the angle between them is fixed.  Is the entire configuration still flexible, or are rods $b$ and $p$ fixed wrt each other?  It is flexible -- the two plates can flap like wings, making $b$ and $p$ have different possible angles.

For a concrete example, let $a = (1,0,0)$, $b = (0,1,0)$, and $p = (0,\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, where $\theta$ is variable.  Then $x$ is fixed (since $a$ and $b$ are constant), $y$ is fixed (since $a\bullet p = 0$ for any $\theta$), but $z$ is variable (since $b\bullet p = \cos\theta$).