# Relationship for cosine of angle

Tags: linear-algebra

If $x$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $a$ and $b$, $y$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $a$ and $p$, and $z$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $b$ and $p$, can we write $z$ in terms of $x$, $y$ and the magnitudes of $a$, $b$, and $p$?

That is, no dot products should appear in the relation.

All vectors are in $4$-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: Bad site for such questions.

Comment: This problem was already posted here, two days earlier: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725948/relationship-for-cosine-of-angle